# Portable lightbox for use in userscripts

Tags: javascript, lightbox, userscripts

I have tried to implement various lightboxes into my userscripts, but I have never gotten them to work. The most common problem is some of them require's you to modify a css/js file, setting where various image files located. If this is not the case, the image must be located on a specific location on the current server. This is of source not possible, when I don't own the servers I wish to modify.

The lighbox should be able to:

- Display one image at once with forward/back arrows.

Not required, but would be nice:

- A numbering of the images at the bottom of the lightbox, allowing to jump to a specific image number.

Please provide an example of it being implemented in an userscript. The script may use the `// @require` and `// @resource` fields.

Comment: Have you tried making your own? They're not that difficult. SO is unlikely to create a whole lightbox userscript for you, but is more likely to help you with one you've nearly completed.

Comment: So you want something that's supposed to be widely supported by many different setups (a plugin) to work _exactly_ with your file structure with no configuration whatsoever, without writing your own lightbox? I hope I'm misunderstanding your question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Lightbox2](http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/), coincidentally the first Google result for "lightbox", doesn't mention the need to edit any CSS / JS files or do anything besides include their scripts on the page, and wrapping the thumbnails with a link to the full sized images. If you've tried this, was there any specific problem with it?

Comment: This does require the some images to be hosted on the current page. If I copy the html of the lightbox 2 main page and paste it in jsFiddle and make everything use absolute links, it will fail at loading "loading.gif" and "closelabel.gif". Also: "Check the CSS and make sure the referenced prev.gif and next.gif files are in the right location. Also, make sure the loading.gif and close.gif files as referenced near the top of the lightbox.js file are in the right location." jsFiddle test: http://jsfiddle.net/aEe6v/

Comment: So, use absolute URLs to a server where you host those files, or data URLs. to include them in the script.